# Vaadin web application with server push doesn't work on OpenShift

Tags: asynchronous, tomcat7, openshift, server-push, vaadin7

I created a simple Vaadin web application with server push that runs just fine locally: https://github.com/breun/lastfm-friend-ranker

I tried to run it on OpenShift using Tomcat 7, but although the interface appears on http://lastfmfriendranker-breunnl.rhcloud.com the application doesn't actually work and I see the following in the log:

```
WARNING: Failed using comet support: org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7AsyncSupportWithWebSocket, error: Tomcat failed to detect this is a Comet application because context.xml is missing or the Http11NioProtocol Connector is not enabled.
If that's not the case, you can also remove META-INF/context.xml and WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-compat-tomcat.jar Is the Nio or Apr Connector enabled?
Mar 01, 2014 11:58:42 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework doCometSupport
WARNING: Using org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7BIOSupportWithWebSocket
Mar 01, 2014 11:58:42 AM org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeInterceptor inspect
SEVERE: IllegalStateException. AsyncWriter is null. WebSocket and org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeInterceptor won't work.
```

Do I need to configure something for async support on OpenShift or something?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my application. Using with the port 8000 seems to work for now until they support websockets on the default proxy.

More info here:
[Vaadin cannot establish Websocket connection on OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967877/vaadin-cannot-establish-websocket-connection-on-openshift)